# Puppeteer : How to make loop of click and extract data from each click?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

The loop does not continue and it only click the first button. and then this error shows :

> Error: Node is detached from document

```
for (let i = 0; i < viewDetails_btns.length; i++) {
  console.log("Number of physicians: ", viewDetails_btns.length);
  console.log("Number of now: ", i);

  // Wait for and click the "View Details" button
  await page.waitForSelector(".docBox span.redColorLink");
  await viewDetails_btns[i].click();

  await page.waitForSelector("b.ng-tns-c12-0");
  const element = await page.$("b.ng-tns-c12-0");
  if (element) {
    const text = await page.evaluate((el) => el.innerText, element);
    console.log(text);
  } else {
    console.log("Element not found");
  }

  await page.waitForTimeout(3000); // Wait for 3 seconds
  // Wait for the "button.btn" and click it
  await page.waitForSelector("button.btn");
  const button = await page.$("button.btn");
  if (button) {
    await button.click();
  } else {
    console.log("Button with class 'btn' not found.");
  }
}
```